# Top Poster Per Taxonomy Term Block View?

Tags: views

I was thinking about make a block view showing who has posted the most posts per term. It will have a tax term argument (D6) I cant work out the best way to go or if its even possible with Views.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Hello ive upgraded to D7 and im loving the taxonomy terms being entities now. Would this be easier to achieve now? Has to be. I was just wanting a 'Top commentators' block view in each taxonomy term page. Anyone? thanks

Comment: some code here might help - http://drupal.org/node/753034 . I dont know if this is too easy or too hard for drupal and thats why there isnt much on it on the net.